# Как понять выражение "return serialSIM900->available();" из библиотеки sim900.h для ардуино?

Tags: c++, arduino

Подскажите как понять выражение "return serialSIM900->available();" из библиотеки sim900.h для ардуино?
Какую роль выполняет оператор стрелка? Функция available(), если я правильно понимаю, выполняет роль Serial.available(). Где в ардуине найти файл с библиотекой Serial.available() что самому ее поковырять?

Ссылка на библиотеку: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/GPRS_SIM900.

Comment: `serialSIM900` - указатель на объект типа `Serial` (или какой там тип вызывает `available()`). `a->b()` - это то же, что и `(*a).b()`.

Comment: подскажите где в ардуине найти объект Serial?

Comment: Я разбираюсь в С++, но не в arduino...

Comment: @Furious_pawn, ну во всех же примерах `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`, эта строка его по сути и добавляет.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите как понять выражение "return serialSIM900->available();" из библиотеки
> sim900.h для ардуино? Какую роль выполняет оператор стрелка?

Выражение возвращает количество байт (символов) доступных для считывания из буфера последовательного порта. Под символами понимаются данные, которые уже приняты и хранятся в последовательном приемном буфере (который может хранить максимум 64 байта). Функция available() является наследником вспомогательного класса Stream. Стрелка - указатель на функцию класса Serial.

> Функция available(), если я правильно понимаю, выполняет роль Serial.available().

Совершенно верно

> Где в ардуине найти файл с библиотекой Serial.available() что самому ее поковырять?

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

Answer (score 0):

Это объект класса SoftwareSerial. Класс определен в файле <путь установки ардуино студии>\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial\src\SoftwareSerial.h